# Convert MS to DD:HH:MM:SS

Tags: node.js

I want to convert time to Days, Hours, Minutes and seconds, i've found this :

```js
    String.prototype.toHHMMSS = function () {
      var sec_num = parseInt(this, 10); // don't forget the second param
      var hours = Math.floor(sec_num / 3600);
      var minutes = Math.floor((sec_num - (hours * 3600)) / 60);
      var seconds = sec_num - (hours * 3600) - (minutes * 60);

      if (hours < 10) {hours = "0"+hours;}
      if (minutes < 10) {minutes = "0"+minutes;}
      if (seconds < 10) {seconds = "0"+seconds;}
      return days+':'+hours+':'+minutes+':'+seconds;
  }
```

But i don't know how to display 1 day when hours is superior then 24 hours

**Thanks !**

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by dividing seconds by sec_num / (3600 * 24) kind of same as you did for hours just multiply it by 24, below is the updated working code.

```
 String.prototype.toHHMMSS = function () {
      var sec_num = parseInt(this, 10); // don't forget the second param
      var days = Math.floor(sec_num / (3600 * 24));
      var hours = Math.floor((sec_num - (days * (3600 * 24))) / 3600);
      var minutes = Math.floor((sec_num - (days * (3600 * 24)) - (hours * 3600)) / 60);
      var seconds = sec_num - (days * (3600 * 24)) - (hours * 3600) - (minutes * 60);

      if (hours < 10) {hours = "0"+hours;}
      if (minutes < 10) {minutes = "0"+minutes;}
      if (seconds < 10) {seconds = "0"+seconds;}
      return days+':'+hours+':'+minutes+':'+seconds;
  }
```